# How can i use websocket in jasmine framework?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I trying to UnitTest using Jasmine framework with websocket. (jasmine-2.4.1 ver.)

websocket `send` function is fine. but `onmessage` function has a problem.

result value is undefined.

Here is my code:

```
var ws;
beforeEach(function() {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://myaddress:port");
});

describe("Module Test", function() {

    it("first test", function (done) {
        //send to server
        ws.onopen = function(e) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({"module":"test","func":"test_func"}));
        };

        var result;
        ws.onmessage = function(e) {
            result = JSON.parse(e.data.rsp);
            console.log(result); // <- this result value is true...
        };

        //server return result value.. and... it is true.....
        //but result value is undefiend....
        expect(result).toBe(true);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting result to be truthy before you receive the message. Forgive me if I've misunderstood the problem, but this should fix your test: -

```
var ws;
beforeEach(function() {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://myaddress:port");
});

describe("Module Test", function () {

    it("first test", function (done) {
        ws.onopen = function(e) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({"module":"test","func":"test_func"}));
        };

        ws.onmessage = function(e) {
            var result = JSON.parse(e.data.rsp);
            expect(result).toBeTruthy();
            done();
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: var result value is undefied.
so, toBeTruthy() doesn't work. :(

Comment: @SunghoPark Apologies... I thought it was 'true' inside your onmessage function, that's what your comment says next to it. That's why I thought it was simple mistake of asserting before the result value was retrieved